# Unhandled Promise Rejection Error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

am getting error while executing combined queries

Am using, sequelize and mysql

Here is my code:

```
const makeAuthenticate = async (req, res) => {
  const newOtp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
  try {
    const {phone} = req.body;
    
    const [user, created] = await db.User.findOrCreate({
      where: { phone: phone },
    })
      .then(e => {
         db.User.update({ otp: newOtp }, {
          where: {
            phone: phone
          }})
            .then(f => res.status(200).json({
              otp: newOtp
            }))
            .catch(err => res.status(500).json({error: err})) // Error comes from here !
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(500).json({error: err})) 
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({error: error.message})
  }
}
```

And here is what am doing with the code:

Basically, am doing both signup and signin in single query, in other words at first  using findOrCreate - i find the user or i will create a new user, and then i need to send one time password (which is temp 6 digit numerics") to the phone number which they use on the process.

So, am updating the otp to my users table and then i need to add up the call to send SMS to the user ( i havent done that yet ) so as of now am at the stage of findOrCreate and make another update call to the specific user.

By this am getting an error as follows:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
const makeAuthenticate = async (req, res) => {
  const newOtp = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000)
  const {phone} = req.body
  
  try {
    const [user, created] = await db.User.findOrCreate({
      where: { phone: phone }
    })

    const updatedRes = await db.User.update({ otp: newOtp }, { where: { phone: phone }})

    res.status(200).json({
      otp: newOtp
    })
  } catch(e) {
    res.status(500).json({error: err})
  }
}
```

There is no need to nest promises and `.then()` you can just use `await` since `Sequelize` uses promises.

The main issue with your code is that you use `.catch()` inside `try catch`and they both are trying to send a status on failure. So most likely your issue is somewhere else but this was a side effect, when you run my code you should see your real issue if it exist.